# Change sticky status of posts from phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, sticky-post, post-status, wp-update-post, phpmyadmin

I have many sticky posts in my database. Is there any SQL function which I could use from phpMyAdmin to change (remove) sticky status of posts, if post is sticky to change it to not sicky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sticky posts info is stored in the `sticky_posts` option in the options table.

It's stored as serialized array e.g. `a:2:{i:0;i:1272;i:1;i:1995;}`

You can modify it via the [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) but there's a way to bulk edit posts in the backend:

**1. Select the Sticky view:**

[image: 1]

**2. Select all sticky posts and apply the bulk Edit action:**

[image: 2]

**3. Make them non-sticky:**

[image: 3]

and press update.